# How to solve the validator.proto file not found error?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am getting the following error :

> github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto: Import
> "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto" was not found or had errors.
> github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto:18:8:
> "google.protobuf.FieldOptions" is not defined.
> github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto:22:8:
> "google.protobuf.OneofOptions" is not defined.
> pkg/cnskcprotobuf/cnskcprotobuf.proto: Import
> "github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto" was not found
> or had errors.

When i run the command :

```
> protoc --go_out=. \   --proto_path=${GOPATH}/src \
>   --proto_path=${GOPATH}/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/ \
>   --proto_path=${GOPATH}/src/github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/ \
>   --proto_path=. \
> --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative pkg/test/test.proto --govalidators_out=. --govalidators_opt=paths=source_relative
```

I updated GOPATH = /usr/local.
Validator.proto file is present in the following paths in my system.

```
./usr/local/src/github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto
./usr/local/pkg/mod/github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators@v0.3.2/validator.proto
```

Can anyone tell a solution for this error ?